# Can't import Java Class inside JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

This is my project's structure in NetBeans

[Project's Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkU0l.png)

I am trying to import the User.java file like that

```
<%@page import="User"%>
```

so then i can use it like that

```
<%
User user = (User) session.getAttribute("currentUser");
if (user == null) {
    response.sendRedirect("login_page.jsp");
}   
%>
```

This file is inside src folder but without a package name.
I tried to use import="package.User" but that doesn't seem to work either.

Does anybody knows what is wrong with my structure?
Thank you.

Comment: Why cant you rename the default package. Try after renaming it. You may find easy to solve.

Comment: Why? This shouldn’t be done in scriptlets anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can't import classes from the default package. You'll have to put your classes in packages and import them with their fully qualified name: *packagename.classname*